# Need location of image for preference pane "PREF" icon

Tags: macos, dock, preferences, icon, system-settings

I have a stack in my Dock with aliases to my most-used preference panes. In the past, the icons that appear in the grid when I click on the stack have been the large descriptive icons shown in Finder. Since upgrading to Lion, instead, I'm getting new icons. The descriptive icon is small, surrounded by a gear, and the word PREF is under it. At a glance, it's no longer possible to tell which preference pane is which.

Finder doesn't show these large "gear/PREF" icons; the stack and QuickLook do.

Where might I find the image for this icon so I can start figuring out how to replace it? It's nowhere inside the packages for the individual preference panes, System Preferences.app, or Dock.app.

Comment: Did this work differently in Snow Leopard? Can you upload a picture of what this looks like?

Comment: It appears the "gear/PREF" icon is the icon preview generated for .prefPane files; and the Dock seems to always show icon previews. If you can find a way to either disable quick look for .prefPane files or find a way to turn off icon previews in the Dock, they should show their proper icons.

Answer (score 1):

You lift the the icon of any prefpane by the "get info trick" 
http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2493

Also I'm seeing icons in the prefpane bundles in Contents/Resource/xxxx.icns

Comment: The link appears to be broken. This is why we encourage posts on Ask Different to include the content of the answer in the post, and not just a link.